# How to solve Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses' in flutter

Tags: flutter

When I want to run the apps, I get the error

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

The packages I use are:

- image_picker: ^0.8.3+2
- video_player: ^2.1.13
- video_editor: ^1.2.0

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.package-info found in modules jetified-exoplayer-common-2.14.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-common:2.14.1) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.13.2-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.13.2)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 53s
```

How can I solve this?

after add

**dependency_overrides:**

**video_player: 2.1.13**

```
e: D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock-0.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\creativemaybeno\wakelock\Wakelock.kt: (8, 16): Redeclaration: Wakelock
e: D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock-0.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\creativemaybeno\wakelock\Wakelock.kt: (41, 7): Redeclaration: NoActivityException        
e: D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock-0.5.3+3\android\src\main\kotlin\creativemaybeno\wakelock\Wakelock.kt: (8, 16): Redeclaration: Wakelock
e: D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock-0.5.3+3\android\src\main\kotlin\creativemaybeno\wakelock\Wakelock.kt: (41, 7): Redeclaration: NoActivityException      

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':wakelock:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions in "Try: ..."?

Comment: thank you for your reply.  "Try: ..." is?

Comment: The text in the error message.

Comment: the error message I get I has write in the question

Comment: It seems you didn't understand what I mean. I meant: "Did you try any of the suggestions that are written in the error message (which you have included in your question), namely: `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.`"

Comment: Can I know what is the comment? I try to run --stacktrace but it says nexpected token 'stacktrace' in expression or statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `pubspec.lock` and run `flutter pub get`.

Basically, there is version mismatch due to video_editor using v2.1.12 of video_player as dependency which in turn uses exoplayer.

This is the simple way.

The other option is to use dependency override but it's not safe

```
dependency_overrides:
  video_player: 2.1.13
```

Reference doc for dependency override
https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides

Comment: thank you for your reply. after I add dependency_overrides, I get another error. I have updated my question. It show another error

Comment: you shouldn't be having this problem in the first place. But if it is, try overriding `wakelock: 0.5.3+3` as well.

Comment: after I flutter clean and flutter run. no error already thanks

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
1. flutter clean

2. flutter run
```