# Flutter - How to solve Execution failed for task ':app:checkProductionDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: flutter

i got this issue when i try to run or build apk/aab my app

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkProductionDebugDuplicateClasses'.
 > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DownloadNotificationHelper found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.17.0-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.17.0) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.15.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.15.1)
Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 40s
```

dependecies that i use:

```
dependencies:
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9

  #http
  http: ^0.13.4

  #firebase things
  firebase_core: ^1.13.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.9
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.5.3
  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.2
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.8
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.0.8

  #google auth
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.4

  #facebook auth
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.1.1

  # font and icons
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0

  #state management
  provider: ^6.0.2

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.0
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.20
  crypto: ^3.0.1
  location: ^4.3.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  permission_handler: ^8.3.0
  geolocator: ^8.2.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2

  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  video_player: ^2.2.19
  youtube_player_iframe: ^2.2.2
  flutter_html: ^2.2.1
```

Anyone can help? I already follow and tried this solution ([How to solve Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses' in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813529/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugduplicateclasses-in-flut)) but it doesn't work for me.